# How can I get the points on the trimmed surface with eyeshot?

Tags: trim, surface, eyeshot

I catch a curve while creating a plane to section with a trimmed cylinder model, I want to get some points both on this curve and on the trimmed surface. for example, point P is a point on the curve, I called Surface.Trimming.IsPointInside(p) to check it is exist on the surface or not, all points on the curve are on the trimmed surface.

[a plane section with the trimmed cylinder surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6wFQ.png)
the point 1,2,3,4,5,6 is on the section curve, but only point 1 and 2 is on the trimmed surface.

How can I get the right points both sectioned curves and trimmed surface?